# jQuery code injection not working on page that already has jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension that a right click action on an object in Tab A will impact some activity on Tab B that has an admin html page I control. I've successfully injected some code into page B. Page B natively uses jQuery and I'd like to use jQuery in my injection code, but I get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

My extension code:

```
function AddAsinInTab(asin,tab) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab["id"], { code: 'jQuery("a").css("color","red");'});

}
```

The same code at the bottom of the admin page A works fine on page load:

```
<script>
    jQuery("a").css("color","blue");
</script>
```

Comment: @gthacoder. I already tried that. I still get : `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide many details, but it seems like your executed script simply doesn't see the jQuery file in the page. I would try to load jQuery along with your programmatic injection. Something like this may help (your should have *jquery-1.10.2.min.js* file in the same directory as your extension):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab["id"], { file: "jquery-1.10.2.min.js" }, function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab["id"], { code: 'jQuery("a").css("color","red");' });
});
```

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment describes why this happens: "Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page." Since jQuery is a bunch of JavaScript variables and functions, the extension has to inject it itself.